# Installing /whisk.system/messaging package in my local installation

Tags: serverless-framework, openwhisk, serverless-architecture

I am doing my local openwhisk installtion on Ubuntu 16.04. 
I was try to do my hands-on on the below sample
https://github.com/IBM/openwhisk-data-processing-message-hub

it using /whisk.system/messaging package 
but when i check the installed packages i see below

```
/whisk.system/alarms                                                   
/whisk.system/watson-translator                                        
/whisk.system/github                                                  
/whisk.system/weather                                                
/whisk.system/watson-textToSpeech                                      
/whisk.system/slack                                                   
/whisk.system/utils                                                   
/whisk.system/combinators                                              
/whisk.system/samples                                                  
/whisk.system/websocket                                                
/whisk.system/watson-speechToText
```

Can someone let me know how to install the messaging package

Answer (score 1):

The messaging package relies on a microservice that relays Kafka messages as OpenWhisk trigger fires. You can find instructions on how to build and deploy the microservice, as well as the actions in the messaging package here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-kafka/issues/99#issuecomment-300536379